# JFXPanel в Swing приложении

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Есть приложение, которое начал писать на `swing` . Затем узнал, что график удобнее нарисовать с помощью `JavaFx` и `JFXPanel` Пробую пока примеры [отсюда](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm) Сам [раздел с примерами](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE)

Вот первый пример:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initAndShowGUI();

        }
    });
}


private static void initAndShowGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    gui = new GUI();

    frame.add(gui.create());
    frame.add(fxPanel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initFx(fxPanel);
        }
    });
}

private static void initFx(JFXPanel panel){
    Scene scene = createScene();
    panel.setScene(scene);
}

private static Scene createScene(){
 Group  root  =  new  Group();
    Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
    Text  text  =  new Text();

    text.setX(40);
    text.setY(100);
    text.setFont(new Font(25));
    text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");

    root.getChildren().add(text);

    return (scene);
}
```

GUI — это мой класс-наследник `JPanel` на которой вот такая таблица, в которую надо точки вводить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда добавляю ее на `frame`, то таблицы не видно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как тогда добавлять на панель кнопки из swing? Еще хотелось бы узнать, как запустить рисовку `JFXPanel` по нажатию на кнопку, как я сделал на `swing`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на кнопку аппроксимировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мож вопрос будет не в тему, но почему вы используете и swing и javaFx ? может быть лучше будет просто javaFx использовать?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Не хочется переписывать интерфейс заново. Надеюсь из Fx использовать только Chart и все с ним связанное.